# Type Mismatch resolution

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which extracts data from two sheets and concatenates it together into one row.

I am having a type mismatch error when I run the piece of code which merges the data based on Account Number. The error appears on the *d line below.

This is my test data.

```
Acc Num         Name            Date of Birth   Country Revenue  Start Date
25769886    Andreas Ottmar  07/01/1962  DE  106330   01/04/2017
```

Code:

```
 With Worksheets("customerrevenue")
For x = 2 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   *** key = .Cells(x, 2).Value & "|" & .Cells(x, 3).Value & "|" & .Cells(x, 4).Value
    If list.Count = 0 Then ReDim results(0 To 5, 0 To 0)

    If list.Contains(key) Then
        IndexOf = list.LastIndexOf(key)
        results(0, IndexOf) = results(0, IndexOf) & " & " & .Cells(x, 
      1).Value
        results(4, IndexOf) = results(4, IndexOf) + .Cells(x, 5).Value
        results(5, IndexOf) = results(5, IndexOf) & " & " & .Cells(x, 
       6).Value
```

Declarants:

```
 Dim key As Variant, values As Variant, results As Variant
  Dim list As Object
  Dim x As Long, IndexOf As Long
  Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

Comment: try `key = join(application.transpose(application.transpose(.Cells(x, 2).resize(1, 3).Value)), "|")`

Comment: typically a quick look at the code line and the error code would indicate that one of those three cells held a worksheet error code.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I am getting the same error on the same line.

Comment: What is the declaration of key?

Comment: I have added the declarants now.

Comment: Does it throw error at first run of the loop, or just at one point? Do you have `key` declared? You can also try casting values to string: `CStr(.Cells(x, 2).Value) & "|" & CStr(.Cells(x, 3).Value) & "|" & CStr(.Cells(x, 4).Value)`

Comment: The problem should be from the date. Converting to string, as @brainac suggests, seems a good idea but I would also declare `key As String`.

Comment: Hi guys, this seems to of fixed the problem, thankyou.